# Linux TCP socket dropping messages with no error

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, flash, tcp

I have a chat server in c++/linux and a chat client in Flash (AS3). I'm using TCP sockets to communicate between the server and client. Up until recently everything has been going smoothly and I have never had a dropped message but I implemented some new functionality in my code that writes many messages to the user in a short amount of time but the client isn't receiving some of the messages.

In my server I check the write() call for any error message

```
if(write(fd, str->c_str(), size) != size)
{
    cout << "Error with write." << endl;
}
```

And my server never complains to me. TCP is suppose to never drop packets.. it's almost like Flash is deliberately blocking some of my incoming messages when I try to send multiple messages down the socket in a short period of time.

Anyone have a clue as to what is going on? All debugging has failed me thus far :(

Comment: From the limited information you've provided, I'm going to guess you don't grok that TCP is a _stream_ and has no concept of individual "packets". I suspect the data you're sending gets clumped together, received all at once and you only read the message from the beginning of it.

Comment: You can use Wireshark to sniff the data stream and find out if the packets are being recived.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Right you were sir, I do not grok that TCP is a stream. My messages were getting clumped together and sent at once. Since I was dealing with strings it would clump multiple strings (and their null terminating characters together), thus I did not notice there was more data. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem. Remember they might arrive split up, too (but the chunks will always be in the right order). I guess you probably want to buffer until you hit a null-terminator, if that's your delimiter.

Comment: @James: you might wish to expand your comment into an answer. Your guess was dead-on. :)